# Xamarin - How to Bind Data From Rest API to a StackLayout NOT ListView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I am trying to bind data into the labels inside StackLayout using data fetched from my REST API, but it's not displaying any data.

I'm able to fetch the data, but I'm wondering how I can bind that data using BindingContext? I don't want to bind the data to a ListView, but inside a StackLayout.

> ViewTask.xaml:

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Padding="13, 5">
    <StackLayout Padding="13, 7">
        <Label Text="Task Name: " Font="Bold"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Padding="13, 7">
        <Label Text="Created By: " Font="Bold"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Creator}" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Padding="13, 7">
        <Label Text="Status: " Font="Bold"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Status}" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Padding="13, 7">
        <Label Text="Date Created: " Font="Bold"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Timestamp}" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Padding="13, 7">
        <Label Text="Description: " Font="Bold"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Description}" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

> ViewTask.xaml.cs

```
private int TaskId;

public HttpResponseMessage response;

private ObservableCollection<Task> _task;

public ViewTask(int tId)
{
    TaskId = tId;
    FetchTaskView();

    InitializeComponent();
}

async void FetchTaskView()
{
    Title = "Task #: " + TaskId;

    if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet)
    {
        var apiResponse = RestService.For<ITasksApi>(UserSettings.Url);
        response = await apiResponse.GetTasks();

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var taskContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Task>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            _task = new ObservableCollection<Task>(taskContent);

            BindingContext = _task.Where(t => t.Id == TaskId).ToList();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("No internet connection. Unable to fetch task data.", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }
}
```

Comment: you want a BindableLayout - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Task Class should contains properties with getter and setter.

```
public class Task
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Creater { get; set; }
   .....
}
```

then use

```
BindingContext = _task.Where(t => t.Id == TaskId).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding YourList}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Your PropertyName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
```

here is the code how you can bind your list to stacklayout